# Output part of the response in AJAX from a php form action

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a form which POST's its data via AJAX:

```
$.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "http://example.com/prp/resources/upscalc.php",  
          data: dataString,  
          success: function(data){       
            res=data;  
            alert (res);return false; 
          }  
        });
```

And what is being outputted to the page is currently this:
[image: Form response]

What do I need to do so the only value I alert out is the number(in this case $66.52) at the end of the alert?

P.s. additional information, the xml at the top is from a UPS api call, and I cannot get rid of it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Btw, there is some interesting information inside the XML, such as `responseStatusCode` and what seems like a cost breakdown as well.

Comment: I might use it in the future, but right now I don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about -

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "http://example.com/prp/resources/upscalc.php",  
    data: dataString,  
    success: function(data){       
        res=data.split('-->');
        alert (res[res.length-1]);
        return false; 
    }  
});
```

Edit: *Thanks to David for the idea that "-->" could potentially exist in the UPS response, and it's safer to lop off the last element of the array rather than the second*

Comment: This is what I was thinking.  You're going to have to do some string manipulation to get the desired output, since you have no control over what UPS's API returns.

Answer (score 0):

```
var resNum=res.split("$");
var resNum="$"+resNum[resNum.length-1];
```

Comment: This would work, but @ThiloSavage got there first, thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({  
          type: "POST",  
          url: "http://example.com/prp/resources/upscalc.php",  
          data: dataString,  
          success: function(data){       
            res=data;  
            alert (res.substr(-7));return false; 
          }  
        });
```

Comment: This won't work if the value is not 6 digits ($1.00 or $100.00)

Comment: as @ThiloSavage nice idea, but since I would not have control over the values length it is not dynamic enough.

Comment: @ThiloSavage - I know it won't always work, I was just proposing an alternative approach

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how the response seems to end with the amount, you can run this regular expression:

```
data.match(/(\$[\d.]+)\s*$/)[1];
```